# Erasure error, while using generic types in methods with similar signature

Tags: java, generics

I want to have the following:

User
UserDto
UserMapper

```
userDto = userMapper.map(user);
user = userMapper.map(userDto);
```

My idea is to have a class similar to this:

```
public interface EntityMapper<E, D> {
    E map(D dto);
    D map(E entity);
}
```

but i am getting the following error:

> 'map(D)' clashes with 'map(E)'; both methods have same erasure

How can i achieve this without having 2 functions to map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both `map(D dto)` and `map(E entity)`, essentially have the same signature. being `map(Object dto)` and `map(Object entity)`. And there is no way for java to determine which method is being called when you call `entityMapper.map(something);`
So, you need to define your method as follows:

```
public abstract class EntityMapper{
   public abstract <E extends AbstractEntity, D extends AbstractDto> E map(D dto);
   public abstract <E extends AbstractEntity, D extends AbstractDto> D map(E entity);
}
```

Comment: On another note, I suggest you to take a look at the ModelMapper library. It is a very neat, intelligent and efficient library that does the heavy lifting for you. So you will not need to implement the logic of conveting different objects to one another yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, too:

```
public interface EntityMapper<D extends AbstractDTO, E extends AbstractEntity> {
    E map(D dto);
    D map(E entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you:

```
import org.mapstruct.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 

@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public abstract class EntityMapper{

    public abstract E map(D dto);
    public abstract D map(E entity);
 }
```